# Game Error [201] while login in LOTRO

Tags: technical-issues, lord-of-the-rings-online

Few years ago I uninstalled the game from this PC.

Yesterday I tried to install it again but everytime after I chose my server I got this error message and the game closes:

[image]

I already tried to re-install the game but I got no success. I have tried to run the game as adminstrador too. But again no success. I saw in some forums to change the permissions. I already did but no success neither.

Does anyone know how to get through this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

I read somewhere that the file downloaded from the LOTRO's website is corrupted.

So I installed Steam and from there I was able to download the game. This way I was able to play without that error appearing.

**EDIT**

I just installed the game via LOTRO's website on my sister's computer. I was able to play without any error. I just don't know why sometimes it works when downloaded via LOTRO's website and sometimes it doesn't.